# what is the time complexity of this program

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

This code computes a^b.. But I am not sure about its complexity

```
def powerFunc(a,b):

    if b==1:
        return a
    elif b==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return a*powerFunc(a,b-1)

a=int(input())
b=int(input())
print(powerFunc(a,b))
```

Comment: If you call `powerFunc(2, 100)` how many times will `powerFunc` be executed? (you can find this by debugging if you can't figure it out). If you call it with `powerFunc(2, 200)`, how many times will `powerFunc` be executed?

Comment: Should be `O(n)` bound by `b` as the number operations grows with the value of `b`.

Comment: ... or just wait ten seconds and someone will tell you the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With recursive functions, you can start with writing down the recurrence relation:

```
T(a,0) = O(1)
T(a,1) = O(1)
T(a,b) = T(a,b-1) + O(1) for b > 1
```

This is a very simple equation with solution

```
T(a,b) = O(b)
```

The space complexity is also O(b) since the function is not tail-recursive.